# Error: kernel headers not found. (But they are in place)

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I'm trying to install the Guest Additions in VirtualBox 4.04. Host OS is Ubuntu desktop 11.04 64bit, guest OS is Ubuntu server 11.10 64bit.

```
$ sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

After some output this line is printed:

```
The headers for the current running kernel were not found.
```

But the headers *are* installed, at least accordingly to `dpkg`:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-headers
linux-headers-3.0.0-12            install
linux-headers-3.0.0-12-server     install
linux-headers-server              install
```

The running kernel is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux foobar 3.0.0-12-server #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 16:36:30 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 X86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How do I fix things so that Guest Additions installer is able to find kernel headers?

**Update: added full output.**

```
The headers for the current running kernel were not found. If the module compilation fails then this could be the reason.

Building the main Guest Additions module ...done.
Building the shared folder support module ...fail!
(Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong)
Installing the Window System drivers ...fails!
(Could not find the X.Org or XFree86 Window System).
```

I don't care for fail #2, because that's a server and I don't need X server. But I need shared folder support.

Some further detail:

```
$ tail /val/log/vboxadd-install.log
..........
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/vfsmod.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
make: *** [vboxsf] Error 2
```

Comment: This is a standard output for Vboxguest additions - are there any other errors indicating that the vbox kernel modules were not correctly compiled?

Comment: @foss Thanks for your input, I have updated my question.

Comment: @MihaiTodor the other question is a possible duplicate of mine, not vice versa as you said. Hint, have a look at the publication date. Regards.

Comment: Yeah, true. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a VirtualBox ubuntu server guest to correctly accept a guest-additions install you will need to have a minimal xorg package install:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core
```

By doing this, you will have the shared-folder support.

As you have found, the guest additions is one very large script - "VBoxLinuxAdditions.run"

You may be able to unpick this file - I wouldnt recommend it, because as newer versions of virtualbox is released, the version of guest-additions is usually bumped as well.

In addition, I would recommend (if you haven't already), install `dkms`.  When newer ubuntu kernels are updated, the guest-additions kernel modules will be automatically compiled.  Without `dkms` you will lose your shared-folder support when a kernel update is made.

[source](http://blog.brettalton.com/2010/04/28/installing-guest-additions-in-virtualbox-for-an-ubuntu-server-guest/)

Comment: This does not solve the problem in any way.

Comment: I strongly recommend against installing these packages. They will bloat your server install and do not solve the problem. You won't get an error message about X11 any more but that's about the only benefit.

Comment: @Panique that solved the problem, otherwise I wouldn't have accepted this answer. I'm not an idiot.

Comment: @Guandalino - it's most likely that the `xserver-xorg` package installed additional packages that were the ones you need. It's like using a chainsaw to cut a blade of grass - it works, just a bit overkill :)

Comment: The answer by dog should be the accepted answer; installing xorg is unnecessary.

Comment: -1 as this answer is misleading.

Comment: FWIW the dkms install cleared this issue up for me

Comment: NOT solved the problem.

Comment: `xserver-xorg is already the newest version.` Similar message for `xserver-xorg-core`, and guest addition installation fails in the same way after doing this. @dog's answer below works.

Comment: Why is this the voted answer? Why was it voted up? I flagged it. As everyone has mentioned: IT ISN'T. Try: https://askubuntu.com/a/202760/169878

Comment: It's working but misleading ... It's like you ask for a knife to cut a rope and he gave u a knife, a chainsaw, a sword and many other unrelated items that slows down your system.

Answer (score 173):

The message is misleading.

In my case it was actually missing dkms so before you install the addition run

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` dkms
```

Comment: This solved the problem  for me too.

Comment: Use the pacakge `linux-headers-generic` as it will always point to the latest kernel header package.

Comment: updating to the latest VirtualBox is what solved it for me, for Ubuntu 13.10 instalation

Comment: This shlould be the accepted answer, you have a server, why bother to install xorg??? install dkms and problem solved!!!

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --assume-yes build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)` and `sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/version.h` will sure help

Comment: @FredericYesidPeñaSánchez Ikr. The accepted answer doesn't actually even offer a solution. Even though I knew that I need to do what **dog** wrote I checked the accepted solution just for kicks and...it didn't work. :D

Comment: This works for me.

Answer (score 17):

*(Even though this question has an accepted answer, I'm adding this answer in case it helps somebody else out...)*

Although I had identical symptoms, I tried out every suggestion to this question, and yet nothing worked. I finally found [this thread suggesting it's the VirtualBox version](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=282969) not being up to date with the Linux kernel version.

So, if nothing works for you, try installing the latest version from: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/ (at time of writing, this was [4.2.6](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.6/) for Debian-based systems).

Comment: Correct. Actually, I've already run into "all of the above": missing kernel headers, obsolete kernel headers, missing dkms package and indeed, out-of-date VBox version.

Answer (score 14):

I fixed this error by installing `dkms` and upgrading my version of VirtualBox. [Turns out](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=282969) old versions of the VirtualBox guest additions often won't work with the latest kernels.

Comment: Installing dkms, reboot, and re-run the install script worked for me. Its also stated in the official doc: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp11274368

Comment: newer versions (of virtualbox are available as deb files from here: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/) They also have the guest additions iso. Using the latest of that fixed things for me.

Comment: Current official doc link: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp46730490388960

Comment: installing dkms worked flawlessly for me.

Answer (score 10):

The answer about you needing X to use guest additions is just ridiculus. The reason it works after installing X is that it pulls libglib as a dependency, but it would be really unnesessary to install the entire X server just to get the additions running.

All the packages you need are the following:

- build-essential
- linux-headers-`uname-r`
- libglib2.0-0

Obviously it's only part of build-essential and libglib that you need, but rather than investigating exactly which packages are necessary it's easier to just let them pull their dependencies.

A sidenote is that these are exactly the same packages that you need for the vmware equivalent "VMware Tools" on a vmware machine.

Answer (score 9):

After installing the suggested packages with the following command:

> `` sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` dkms ``

I upgraded my version of VirtualBox as suggested by dwurf. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried ALL the above solution and I am pretty sure that I have installed the proper headers but still no luck !!!

```
root@test:~# dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-headers
linux-headers-4.0.0-kali1-amd64         install
linux-headers-4.0.0-kali1-common        install
linux-headers-amd64             install
```

And I have also installed latest version of Virtual Box as of today 5.0.4 but still I have the error when trying to install Guest Additions with error

```
The headers for the current running kernel were not found.
```

**Solution :**

In the end what solved my problem is running the `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` from /root directory instead of other directory like /home/ !!!

I was originally running `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` from `/home/` directory and keeps having this dam error but after using command below from root directory, it's fine, problem solved!

```
cp /media/cd-rom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run /root/
chmod 755 /root/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
cd /root
./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

After this you can simply use `reboot`, then you should have Guest Additional done properly and FULL Screen too ! YAY !!!

Comment: I tried this but still doesn't work . Hands up

Comment: does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Usually i install the guest-additions directly via virtualbox (mount cdrom, sh ./VBoxLinuxGuestAddtions.run). However, most linux-distributions offer you a package which can be install via your package-manager. For me following command solved the issue:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

Comment: I tried all the other installation solutions and continued to have problems with the add-ins or the installation script.  This solution solved the root problem directly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this error is cause by using an old version of Virtual Box **or at least a old version of the Guest Additions ISO image.**

I achieved success by downloading a new ISO of the VBox Guest Additions and running the VBoxLinuxAdditions.run script
I went here Virtual Box [download site](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/) and grabbed a new ISO.

For reasons (too dull to go into) I could not update my version of VirtualBox on the (Windows) host, but I could copy the new ISO file to a local place on the file-system.

Then, In the "Devices" menu on the VM window I chose a new virtual CD/DVD and picked the place where I downloaded the new ISO image.

Then inside the Debian VM I went to `\media\cdrom` and ran the new `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` script as root. (I had already installed dkms, current kernel headers etc.) Then the script stopped falsely complaining about the missing headers (they were not missing) and built the kernel objects it needed.

The whole reason for doing this was so that X.org would give me additional display resolutions and I could run the VM at a higher res than the conservatively set defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same errors as OP when trying to compile the VirtualBox Guest Additions v4.1.12 in various flavours of K/Ubuntu 13.04 guests.

```
Building the shared folder support module ...fail!
```

This is due to bugs (or unmet expectations) of the VirtualBox Guest Additions against various parts of the linux source (in the GUEST). Unfortunately Oracle chooses to link the VirtualBox Host version very closely to the VirtualBox Guest Additions version, so if there's a bug in the Guest Additions then you have to upgrade the Host at the same time.

I had the following virtualbox versions installed on the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS host:

```
virtualbox       4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.3
virtualbox-dkms  4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.3
virtualbox-qt    4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.3
```

As per instructions at:
    http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/virtualbox?dist=precise

I upgraded to 4.2.10-dfsg-0ubuntu2~ubuntu12.04.1~ppa1 using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:debfx/virtualbox
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
cd ~/.VirtualBox
http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.10/VBoxGuestAdditions_4.2.10.iso
```

Now the K/Ubuntu 13.04 guests can build and install their VirtualBox Guest Additions:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install make gcc build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` dkms
cd /media/VBOXADDITIONS_4.2.10_81404
sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
sudo shutdown -r 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing something.
Try to install

- linux-headers-3.14-kali1-common
- linux-headers-3.14-kali1-amd64
- linux-source-3.14
- libdw1
- libunwind7

For me is kali linux with 3.14

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this problem and fixed it by running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove dkms build-essential linux-headers-*
sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

[More Info](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=62357)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me was removing Virtual Box and installing the latest version from the [VirtualBox website](https://www.virtualbox.org/) (version: 4.3.10 (repo) vs. 4.3.22 (website)).

Answer (score 0):

1. [image]
2. `sudo apt-get install --assume-yes  build-essential  dkms  linux-headers-generic  linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
3. `sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/version.h`
4. [image]

> [image]

5. `sudo reboot`

---

+ bonus: *shared folders "secret" ;)*

6. [image]
7. [image]
8. [image]
9. [image]
10. `sudo gpasswd -a <username> vboxsf`
     [image]
11. `sudo reboot`
12. done.
13. ???
14. profit ;)