# Why do Guest Additions need kernel headers in VirtualBox 4.04.?

Tags: 11.10, virtualbox, guest-additions

I'm trying to install the Guest Additions in VirtualBox 4.04.on ubuntu 11.10

I have this error:

```
The headers for the current running kernel were not found.
If the module compilation fails then this could be the reason.
```

Note that I have already installed the headers but still get this error.

Do you have you an ideas please?

Comment: the headers have already installed !!

Comment: i have done apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions and
in the restart i have this message:
modprobe vboxsf failed!
starting the virtualbox-guest-additions fail !

Comment: Did you install the guest additions in the **guest**? (Edited my answer to make that clear).

Comment: @Takkat yes i have done apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions in ubuntu 11.10
now i canot open the virtual machine 11.10 i don't know why , have you an idea please
it display that starting the virtualbox-guest-additions fail ! it still blocked

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/98416/error-kernel-headers-not-found-but-they-are-in-place ?

Answer (score 11):

I found that installing `dkms` with

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

resolved this error/warning for me. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/202760/56343) answer.

Comment: dkms is not required these days - there's a script over at https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=86144&p=412599&hilit=dkms+necessary#p412428 which might be able to help install guest additions

Comment: This fixed my issue in a  Debian 10 (Buster) VM running under VirtualBox 6.1. The error I was getting `VirtualBox Guest Additions: Kernel headers not found for target kernel`.

Answer (score 9):

This command will install the kernel headers:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Now, try to install the Guest Additions again.

Comment: Also, make sure you have most recent VirtualBox (http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/)

Answer (score 2):

For me (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS host; Ubuntu 13.04 guest; virtualbox 4.1.18 running on the host), it seems that the downloaded guest-additions iso on the host was old, so installing by mounting that iso through vbox's menus failed consistently. There was no package `virtualbox-guest-additions` available  on the guest, so I installed

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

instead, which also pulled in `dkms`, `fakeroot`, `virtualbox-guest-utils`, and `virtualbox-guest-x11`. Then I rebooted the guest, and copy/paste worked (also, the resolution jumped up).

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that ubuntu 11.10 does not ship compiler by default. Try `apt-get install gcc gcc-4.7`

Comment: i'd suggest using `build-essentials`

Answer (score 0):

The message you get may not be related to the failure building the Guest Additions. I usually do see this message but Guest Additions build fine and run as expected.

Here are some steps we can try in case we cannot install the guest additions:

- We may just try to install them again after rebooting the guest OS. If that still does not succeed we can also try to install guest additions as root [from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox).
- It may also be worth to update the guest OS before we install the Guest Additions.
- Older versions of virtual box may have bugs that stand against a successful install of the GA. [Update Virtual Box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-closed-source-version-of-virtualbox/41487#41487) to the current version (at present 4.1.18).
- If all fails you can also download and install the ready-built guest additions from the repositories (these will also run with the PUEL version of Virtual Box but they may be out-dated in some aspects) by running the following in the **guest** Ubuntu:

  ```
   sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions
  ```

Answer (score 0):

First of all find your kernel version by:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ibm **3.5.0-24**-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 7 01:50:30 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Next update apt by:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Finally install your kernel version (3.5.0-24) header package by apt

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-24-generic
```