# "The make utility was not found" - error when installing VirtualBox guest additions on Lubuntu from the CD

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, guest-additions

I installed Lubuntu as a guest OS in VirtualBox, and I tried installing the guest additions as I would in Windows, from "Devices->Insert Guest Additions CD Image... (Host+D)", and then running the `autorun.sh` file.

This failed, however, with these errors:

```
The make utility was not found. If the following module compilation fails then
this could be the reason and you should try installing it.

The gcc utility was not found. If the following module compilation fails then
this could be the reason and you should try installing it.

Building the main Guest Additions module ...fail!
```

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution in the end, instead of installing from the VirtualBox CD, I installed from Lubuntu's repos, using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

After that everything worked - resizing, shared clipboard (after I enabled it, it's disabled by default).

Answer (score 1):

The Virtual Box guest additions need to be compiled on the guest. In a lightweight distribution such as Lubuntu a compiler is not provided with the basic set up.

To be able to compile and install the guest additions provided with and matching our Virtual Box version we need to install the following utilities first:

- [gcc](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gcc) [image: Install gcc]
- [make](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/make) [image: Install make]

Comment: I had tried it, but there were other errors - about kernel headers I think.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and I didn't want to use the out-of-date guest additions from the repos. This is what I did to get the script to run:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` dkms
sudo sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

I found the first line in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/202760/244582).