# Virtualbox guest additions installation fails for shared folder support!

Tags: virtualbox, windows-7, oracle, guest-additions, guest-os

I am trying to setup Ubuntu guest OS on a Windows host system.After creating the new virtual machine, I am trying to install the guest additions and I am running `sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` but running that I am getting the following error,

```
  The headers for the current running kernel were not found. If the following module compilation fails then this could be the reason.

  Building the shsared folder support module ... fail!

  Warning: Unknown version of the X window ystem installed. Not installing X Window system drivers.
```

Virtual box version : 4.3.4-91027

Host system : Windows 7 64 bit

Guest OS : Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit.

**UPDATE**

```
On newer version `4.3.26` it works fine, But I need to make it work on `4.3.4-91027`.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> The headers for the current running kernel were not found. If the following module compilation fails then this could be the reason.
>
> Building the shsared folder support module ... fail!

That gives a clue. Install the headers for your kernel version:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Comment: Doesn't work. `linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic is already the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 58 not upgraded.` On Ubuntu 15.10 running in VirtualBox 5 on Windows 8.1 host.

Comment: @ButtleButkus Is this Ubuntu Server? If so: http://askubuntu.com/questions/98416/error-kernel-headers-not-found-but-they-are-in-place

Comment: Hi kos, yes it is Ubuntu Server. Thanks for the link. I ended up starting over using Ubuntu 14.04.3, and the first thing I did was focus on getting the share working before installing the "AMP" of my LAMP stack. I'm not sure why it worked, but it worked this time. I'll try again with Ubuntu 15.10 another day.

Comment: @ButtleButkus Not sure either but glad that it worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading (Some issues have been addressed with the newer versions of VBox), make sure the versions correlate with the correct (Working) versions of VBox.

Comment: Aah. Sorry I forgot to mention that it is working fine with `4.3.20`.But I need to make it work on `4.3.4`.

Answer (score 0):

I found an hack for this problem, I just took the Guest additions of latest VirtualBox and I installed it.It solved all my problems. :)

Thank you

Comment: Your answer would be much improved if you [edit] your answer and provide version numbers. The current "latest VirtualBox" is unlikely to remain so forever.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the Virtualbox Guest Addition ISO file, try using the following commands in the terminal on the guest Virtual Machine :

Do update:

```
apt-get update
```

Install dependencies

```
apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Install guest additions

```
apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11
```

Use `sudo` before the commands if required.