# virtualbox shared folder - kernel headers not found

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, lubuntu, kubuntu

I have read those questions:
[Why can't I access a shared folder from within my Virtualbox machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456400/why-cant-i-access-a-shared-folder-from-within-my-virtualbox-machine)
and
[Error: kernel headers not found. (But they are in place)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98416/error-kernel-headers-not-found-but-they-are-in-place)

The second question equals mine, but the solutions there do not work.

I have a Kubuntu host with Lubuntu guest system.
When I install the vbox guest additions the logfile states (as in the other questions):

```
  Uninstalling modules from DKMS
  Attempting to install using DKMS

  Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/4.3.10/source ->
          /usr/src/vboxguest-4.3.10

  DKMS: add completed.

  Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

  Building module:
  cleaning build area....
  make KERNELRELEASE=3.16.0-30-generic -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/4.3.10/build..........(bad exit status: 2)
  ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for vboxguest: 4.3.10 not found
  Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.16.0-30-generic (x86_64)
  Consult /var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/4.3.10/build/make.log for more information.
  Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
  grep: /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/build/include/linux/version.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
  make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 modules
  test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (                \
      echo >&2;                                                       \
      echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
      echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
      echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
      echo >&2 ;                                                      \
      /bin/false)
  /var/log/vboxadd-install.log
```

I have virtualbox in version 4.3.10_Ubuntu (its the only version I have found in Kubuntus repos)

Comment: Download the latest VirtualBox version, it's already the 5. Make sure you installed gcc and g++ on your guest.